# What encodings exist in ParAccel?

Tags: amazon-redshift, paraccel

Anybody has a link to ParAccel documentation where I can find all column encodings that ParAccel has with description and examples for each?

Thanks!

Comment: If you meant redshift ones (forked from paraccel) you can find it here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Compression_encodings.html

Comment: I know there should be a dictionary encoding in ParAccel that can replace normalization of columns. However, I can't find such in RedShift documentation.

Comment: Bytedict - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Byte_dictionary_encoding.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RedShift (which is actually a version of ParAccel) has the following encodings:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Compression_encodings.html